# Is there a formula to rearrange 2-D array this way?

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a formula to sort this array

```
 1  2   3
 4  5   6
 7  8   9
 10 11  12
 13 14  15
 16 17  18
 19 20  21
```

to

```
1   4   7
10  13  16
19  2   5
8   11  14
17  20  3
6   9   12
15  18  21
```

where you take the first column and put it first in the 2-d array

These is the position it should be after you reposition it

```
[0][0] --> [0][0]
[1][0] --> [0][1]
[2][0] --> [0][2]
[3][0] --> [1][0]
[4][0] --> [1][1]
[5][0] --> [1][2]
[6][0] --> [2][0]
[0][1] --> [2][1]
[1][1] --> [2][2]
[2][1] --> [3][0]
[3][1] --> [3][1]
[4][1] --> [3][2]
[5][1] --> [4][0]
[6][1] --> [4][1]
[0][2] --> [4][2]
[1][2] --> [5][0]
[2][2] --> [5][1]
[3][2] --> [5][2]
[4][2] --> [6][0]
[5][2] --> [6][1]
[6][2] --> [6][2]
```

I can see the pattern, but can't think of the formula

I think use this, if I am right

```
 for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
   for(int j = 0 ; j < 7 ; j++){
       //do something here
   }
 }
```

Comment: That isn't a "sort", it's a "rearrange" (or something). Certainly not a "sort".

Comment: If you could put the 'Arrays' into a code syntax it would be much easier to figure out

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
public static int[][] rearrange(int[][] input) {
    int rows = input.length, cols = input[0].length, total = rows * cols;
    int[][] output = new int[rows][cols];
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
        output[i / cols][i % cols] = input[i % rows][i / rows];
    return output;
}
```

*Test*

```
int[][] input = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18}, {19, 20, 21}};
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(rearrange(input)));
```

*Output*

```
[[1, 4, 7], [10, 13, 16], [19, 2, 5], [8, 11, 14], [17, 20, 3], [6, 9, 12], [15, 18, 21]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or like this:

```
    for (int j = 0, p = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++, p++) {
            newMatrix[j][i] = oldMatrix[p % 7][p / 7];
        }
    }
```